# can't print median and mean at same time

Tags: sas

Trying to print median and mean at the same time, but I keep getting this error

WARNING: Variable margin already exists on file WORK.STATEE1_MARGINS.

WARNING: The duplicate variables will not be included in the output data set of the output statement
         number 1.

```
proc means data = state1 noprint mean median nway missing;
class ndc;
var margin; 
output out = state1_margins (drop = _type_) median= mean=;
run;
```

I just want an output set with median in one column and mean in the other. Shouldn't I be able to do this with one proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it what to name the two variables.

```
proc means data = state1 noprint mean median nway missing;
class ndc;
var margin; 
output out = state1_margins (drop = _type_) median= mean= /autoname autolabel;
run;
```

Autoname tells it to make it _, which is usually fine.  You can also specify explicitly.  Autolabel tells it to add the statistic to the label as well.

```
proc means data = state1 noprint mean median nway missing;
class ndc;
var margin; 
output out = state1_margins (drop = _type_) median=median_m mean=mean_m;
run;
```

Or whatever you prefer.

Comment: column names both show up as "margin". can they be labeled "median" and "mean"

Comment: Assuming you have SAS 9.2 or newer, the `autolabel` also exists to append median/mean to the labels.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you do not specify output variables. If you just put = without a name for the output variable, it will by default take the name of the variable you applied the operation on.

That is no problem when requesting only 1 statistic. But you request 2.
So first he creates the variable margin to contain the median margin.
But then, it tries to create the variable margin to contain the mean. But it already exists at that point!

Hence, to solve your problem, give different names for the output variables, e.g.:

```
proc means data = state1 noprint mean median nway missing;
    class ndc;
    var margin; 
    output out = state1_margins (drop = _type_) median=median_margin mean=mean_margin;
run;
```

Comment: column names both show up as "margin". can they be labeled "median" and "mean"